# Проблема с отрисовкой в Java

Tags: java, graphics

Пишу небольшую игрушку, отрисовываю с помощью awt graphics.

Только проблема в том, что когда я запустил игрушку на другом компе, отрисовка стала ужасной,
точнее, все отрисовывается, но между вырисовкой объектов на экране белый "25-й кадр".

Может, кто сталкивался с этим?

Comment: Двойная буферизация нужна или что-то такое, не знаком с awt graphics.

Comment: Была подобная проблема, давно. Решил простым забиваем на AWT и использовал Swing, т.к. они похожи довольно. AWT - это совсем не то, чем нужно пользоваться.

Comment: А можно обойтись правильной настройкой конфига java?

Comment: Вот что я нагуглил http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845346/double-buffering-with-awt 
PS AWT - это зло.

Comment: да,очень плохо справляется со скоростной отрисовкой.